# VB.net date displaying in m/d/yyyy if date or month is less than 10

Tags: vb.net

How I can I display it always in mm/dd/yyyy in vb.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Have a look at

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)